# property on template doesn't work

Tags: django, templates, properties

According to the answer: [Can model properties be displayed in a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535977/can-model-properties-be-displayed-in-a-template), I'm trying to make property, which can be shown on template:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

  @property
  def initials(self):
    return "%s.%s." % (self.first_name[0:1], self.last_name[0:1])
```

also tried:

```
 def _get_initials(self):
    return "%s.%s." % (self.first_name[0:1], self.last_name[0:1])

 initials = self._get_initials()
```

and template:

```
{% for i in people %}
  {{ i.initials }}
{% endfor %}
```

but the result is empty string

I change the template to:

```
{% for i in people: %}
  {{ i.instance.initials }}
{% endfor %}
```

but still empty string.

If I use:

```
{% for i in people: %}
  {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm getting the **unicode** result, so the model, form and template are correct

Please don't focus on solving initials problem, because I need property to more complex tasks - it is just an example.

**updated**

I add @property because it doesn't work without so I was looking for solutions...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with properties. Why are you adding a colon to "people"? That will cause the variable to not be found, so there is nothing to iterate over.

Comment: colon was a typo. In my app of course there's no colon. Well, i don't know if I have to use property or not - without property it also doesn't works, so I googled and found the suggestion to use property (link on top of question)

Comment: Then there's nothing wrong with the code you've shown. Are you sure the `i` is what you think it is, ie a list or queryset of `MyClass` objects? Have you restarted your server since you added the method?

Comment: people is set of  set([<MyClass: firstname secondname>]) And restarted many times

Comment: You can always remove @property decorator.. but it should works correctly.

Comment: What happens if you replace the method with something simpler, eg just `print 'foo'`?

Comment: Well, I'm on the way... after hashing some code in method i can see some result... But the amazing part is, that "bad" code doesn't show error, just kicks from method to __unicode__. after def initials i have logger.debug("GOT IT") and never enters. But when I remove some part - it appears... I will describe it in answer when I found the main reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Many thanks for Daniel Roseman for pointing me. The property isn't needed, the instance also: The correct answer is:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

  def initials(self):
    return "%s.%s." % (self.first_name[0:1], self.last_name[0:1])
```

also tried:

and template:

```
{% for i in people %}
  {{ i.initials }}
{% endfor %}
```

My problem was definetely somewhere else - i need function to make md5hash of name:

```
def hashed(self):
  hashed = md5.new("%s" % self.first_name).digest()
  return "%s md5(%s)" % (self.first_name, hashed)
```

but there's an error - it has to be hexdigest() not digest(). But the biggest confusion is, that even with this error I expected to see `Smith md5()` instead `Smith md5(skljhghwgohwgio2534)` but I see nothing...., what misleads me, that problem is with function and template not return value...

This is a lesson for me - small steps and if something doesn't work, check simplier case...

Answer (score 0):

So I encountered the same issue. Unfortunately, Django does not tell you, if that property or function on the model has errors or not. It will just not show anything. If you encounter this issue, try to call the function or method you are trying to display from somewhere else, e.g. `MyModel.some_property` and see if the property returns the data you expect.